# Powershell: Gathering tested items into a list to send in email

Tags: powershell

Problem Summary: I am attempting to write a powershell script to detect outbound open ports from a server, then emailing the name of the server and the array of ports detected as open.

Things I can do at the moment:
Scan and test the outgoing port list (1-1024 ports).
Send an email outlining the which machine is effected.

What I want to do:
Only send the email when any of the 1024 ports are listed as 'open'.
List the ports that were found to be open, ignoring ports that were closed.

Here is my code so far (shamelessly stolen from https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/poking-holes-in-the-firewall-egress-testing-with-allports-exposed/):

```
1..1024 | % {$test= new-object system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient; 
$wait = $test.beginConnect("allports.exposed",$_,$null,$null);
($wait.asyncwaithandle.waitone(250,$false)); 
if($test.Connected){echo "$_ open"}else{echo "$_ closed"}} | select-string " "
Send-MailMessage -From OutboundScanning@domain.com -To Myself@domain.com -SmtpServer mysmtp.domain.com -Subject "$env:computername site has exposed outbound ports" -Body "Please contact NOC and NetSec to correct site of $env:computername . Outgoing ports $openedarray are available for outbound connectivity."
```

Comment: All those semicolons and echo (aka Write-Host). Output to the screen is the PowerShell default. As for this... ["What I want to do: ..."] This is If/Then, Try/Catch, statements. Samples in the Powershell_ISE snippets, help files, and online. Your post says you are new to PowerShell and that's fine, yet spend time learning it. Tons on Youtube/docs to guide you. You are literally asking folks to take a script you found elsewhere, and fix it so it works for your end goals. Meaning, please do my work for me, which is the reason someone already downvoted you. Sometimes a kind sole just might.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. The problem I have is more fundamental, I think. I have tried to understand and if/else and a try/catch, but where I struggle is nesting those types of commands so that I can create a set of commands that execute only when certain conditions are met. I have been watching a great series recommended by a colleague for the past few weeks before this, but I'm hitting a wall with understanding. I appreciate the patience nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to provide a bit of edification, but on your next trip here, the rules are:

> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
>
> [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

```
# Refactor and fixes to make this more readable
1..1024 | 
ForEach {
    <#
    Unless you are using a legacy version of PowerShell, why are you using the .Net 
    namespace vs using the built-in PowerShell cmdlet ... 

    # Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
    (Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection).Parameters
    (Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection).Parameters.Keys
    Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Examples
    <#
    # Results

    Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel "Detailed"
    Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -InformationLevel "Detailed"
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "www.contoso.com" -InformationLevel "Detailed"
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName www.contoso.com -DiagnoseRouting -InformationLevel Detailed
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "www.contoso.com" -ConstrainInterface 5 -DiagnoseRouting -InformationLevel "Detailed"

    Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Full
    Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Online    
    #>
```

Your fix is to put the Send mail thing in the if statement.

Yet, you are saying 'if any', which means on the first open hit, you need to exit the loop.

```
$test = new-object system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

$wait = $test.beginConnect("allports.exposed",$_,$null,$null)
($wait.asyncwaithandle.waitone(250,$false))

if($test.Connected)
{
    "$PSItem open"

    $SendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From       = "OutboundScanning@domain.com"
    To         = "Myself@domain.com"
    SmtpServer = "mysmtp.domain.com"
    Subject    = "$env:computername site has exposed outbound ports" 
    Body       = "Please contact NOC and NetSec to correct site of $env:computername. 
                 Outgoing ports $openedarray are available for outbound connectivity."
    }

Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageSplat

Break
}
else{"$PSItem closed"}
}
```

You could refactor this using the normal PowerShell cmdlets, to this...

```
$SendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From       = "OutboundScanning@domain.com"
    To         = "Myself@domain.com"
    SmtpServer = "mysmtp.domain.com"
    Subject    = "$env:computername site has exposed outbound ports" 
    Body       = "Please contact NOC and NetSec to correct site of $env:computername. 
                  Outgoing ports $openedarray are available for outbound connectivity."
}

1..1024 | 
ForEach{
    If (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Port $PSItem)
    {
        # Using Write-Host because of using colorized text, otherwise not really needed, since output to the screen is the PowerShell default.
        Write-Host "Port $PSItem on the target host open. Sending email notification and exiting." -ForegroundColor Red
        # Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageSplat
        Break
    }
}
```

To do this as a collection ($openedarray), then you need to set it so, which you are not showing at all. This will also be very slow, just an FYI...

So, stuff like this...

```
$OpenPorts = @()
$SendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From       = "OutboundScanning@domain.com"
    To         = "Myself@domain.com"
    SmtpServer = "mysmtp.domain.com"
    Subject    = "$env:computername site has exposed outbound ports" 
    Body       = "Please contact NOC and NetSec to correct site of $env:computername. 
                  Outgoing ports $OpenPorts are available for outbound connectivity."
}


1..1024 | 
ForEach{
    If (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Port $PSItem)
    {
        Write-Host "Port $PSItem on the target host open. Continnuing collection" -ForegroundColor Red
        $OpenPorts += ,$PSItem
    }
}


If ($OpenPorts -ge 1)
{
    Write-Warning -Message "A total of $($OpenPorts.Count) ports discovered as open. Sending email notificaiton and exiting."
    # Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageSplat
}
```

Why would you want to send hundreds of ports in the body of an email?

It would be more prudent, to generate a txt/csv/excel report that you can just send. If you really want this in an email, then you need to generate this as a table using HTML body.

Comment: Thank you for this additional guidance. The reason I want/need to do an 'any' clause on ports and exit the condition is that no outbound ports should be available. The thinking was to act as a "canary in the coalmine" and trigger an alert if any access was available. I will go back to the drawing board with this, as the formatting makes a lot more sense in the built-in commands and refactored code.

Comment: Understood and if this gets you to where you need to be, then be sure to mark it as your accepted answer for the benefit of others who may find themselves in the same need and come across this in their searches.

Comment: I've added additional markers so that I can continue using the variables elsewhere in the script I'm building, namely $script:variable. Thank you for your patience with this

Comment: The scope is a thing, for any code blocks (functions, variables, local, remote, etc...), and proper implementation for a given use case must be considered.